# Handling Artifactory Maven Repository URL reidrect

Tags: maven, repository, pentaho, artifactory, nexus

Via the jfrog artifactory version: 4.14.0 dashboard, when adding a remote maven repository, the repository is browsable at one url but the downloads are on a different url.

Example:
https://nexus.pentaho.org/service/rest/repository/browse/omni/pentaho-library/libfonts/5.0.1-stable/

Download a file from that service DOES NOT resolve to
https://nexus.pentaho.org/service/rest/repository/browse/omni/pentaho-library/libfonts/5.0.1-stable/libfonts-5.0.1-stable.jar

It leads to
https://nexus.pentaho.org/repository/omni/pentaho-library/libfonts/5.0.1-stable/libfonts-5.0.1-stable.jar

Convert:

https://nexus.pentaho.org/service/rest/repository/browse/omni/

to

https://nexus.pentaho.org/repository/omni/

---

Looked into user plugins such as this
https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/download/modifyNuGetDownload/modifyNuGetDownload.groovy but these change the path after the base url, not the repository url itself

---

Is there a way to supply a custom repository url for downloading files?

Comment: I tried making a virtual that points to two remotes, one for each of your paths. That lets me download files  that I know are there, and it lets me browse the folders, but I can't see the files in the browser. I think the problem is not the files themselves, but rather the folders that contain them: Artifactory doesn't recognize the links on the folder page because they point somewhere it doesn't expect, so it thinks those folders are empty. I don't think there's any way around this.

Comment: Are you sure the service is Artifactory? the urls seems like it is nexus. It is a different product.

Comment: @gba OP wants to point an Artifactory remote at a Nexus instance.

Comment: @DarthFennec you are correct. I am able to get Arifactory to recognize the folders but not the files inside the folders. My understanding is that it attempts to parse the links inside the directory but since they resolve to a different URL it does not find them. The file in the folder "libfonts-5.0.1-stable.jar" is not actually located at the browsing url https://nexus.pentaho.org/service/rest/repository/browse/omni/pentaho-library/libfonts/5.0.1-stable/